# ansible yum remove - Failed to download packages

Tags: ansible, redhat, yum

When I try to uninstall docker on a RHEL 8 box using Ansible I get the following error

```
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to download packages: containers-common-1:1.2.2-10.module+el8.4.0+11311+9da8acfb.x86_64: Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success", "results": []}
```

If I SSH into the same host as the ansible user and run a manual `yum remove docker docker-client docker-client-latest....` the packages are removed successfully.

Here is my Ansible code

```yaml
---
- name: Remove PodMan
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: uninstall podman
    package:
      name:
        - docker 
        - docker-client 
        - docker-client-latest 
        - docker-common 
        - docker-latest 
        - docker-latest-logrotate 
        - docker-logrotate 
        - docker-engine 
        - podman 
        - runc
      state: absent
```

I have also tried the "yum" module rather than package, but I get the same error.

Here is my Ansible version

```
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.2]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ansible/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.11.2 (main, Jun  6 2023, 07:39:01) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] (/usr/bin/python3.11)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally. If the problem proves intractable, you could always replace this task with a `command` task and just run `yum remove -y ...`.

Comment: @larks, thanks for the suggestion. Using the command module works as expected. I will have to stick with this for the time being and see if I can debug what is going on with the yum module at a later date. Thanks again.

Comment: Got the same issue, happens only with the user ansible i've created just for the purpose of running playbooks locally. Used as well the command trick and it solved the issue for the time being. Looks like a ansible yum module bug. Ansible 2.13 here.

Answer (score -1):

```html
---
- name: uninstall packages
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    packages:
      - docker
      - podman
  tasks:
    - name: uninstall
      yum:
        name: "{{item}}"
      state: absent
      loop: "{{packages}}"
```

The Ansible playbook is used for uninstalling the packages on all hosts. It loops through all packages and uninstall one by one. It uses the yum module.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**